# Play music during a call

Tags: android

Is it possible during a call, to play a song on my android phone and just the person I'm talking to hears the music?

Comment: last I knew there was no public API for playing audio into the phone call "stream"

Comment: I've played music via AudioManager durning a call, however the person on the other end was not able to hear it.